# Fibres of the target map related (homeomorphic) to the fibres of the source map in a topological groupoid?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

In Butz, Moerdijk, *Representing topoi by topological groupoids*, Section 4, it is said that in order to prove that the fibres in a point $p$ of the source (domain) and target (codomain) maps (respectively $s$ and $t$) are both homeomorphic to some space $En(S_p)$, it suffices to prove it just for the source map.

Why is this true? Does it come from some form of abstract relationship (homeomorphism?) between $s^{-1}(p)$ and $t^{-1}(p)$ that I can't see?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are homeomorphic by the inverse map $i:G\to G$.  Since $i$ interchanges sources and targets, it maps $s^{-1}(p)$ to $t^{-1}(p)$ (and is a homeomorphism because it is its own inverse).